# how to remove CSSTransition when widow resize

Tags: css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

```
import {CSSTransition} from "react-transition-group";
 
<CSSTransition
            in={focused} timeout={200} classNames="slide">
             <NavSearch className={focused ? "focused" : ""}
                 onFocus={() => {
                  handleInputFocus()}}
                 onBlur={handleInputBlur}>
             </NavSearch>
</CSSTransition>
```

**Css**

```
 .slide-enter{
        transition:all .2s ease-out;
    }
    .slide-enter-active{
        width:320px;
    }
    .slide-exit{
        transition:all .2s ease-out;
    }
    .slide-exit-active{
        width:240px;
    }
```

**Problem: When I resize my widow width I want to remove these transitions. But I don't know how to write my code.**

```
 @media(max-width:1200px){
     
    }
```

Comment: did you try `transition:none;` ?

Comment: if you means add `transition:none` to the `@media (max-width:1200px){ }`, I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Set it to its default  `transition: all 0s ease 0s` ([w3schools: CSS transition Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp))

Comment: sorry it doesn't work on react transition group  @Rene van der Lende

Comment: I'm sure React too has some transition duration parameter, set that to 0s (zero seconds), essentially disabling the transition...

Comment: yeah, I agree with your idea, but  I don't know why it didn't work. so I just change my code like this `@media{max-width:1200px{.slide-exit-active{
            width:100%;
            } }}` it works now thanks to your suggestion @Rene van der Lende